# JSON response from Python json.dumps

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am trying to send a Django HttpResponse encoded as JSON to Javascript.

Python:

```
response_data = {}
response_data['status'] = 'incomplete'
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Jquery:

```
function auth_request(){
  $.ajax({
    url: AUTH_ENDPOINT + "myid0001",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(response){

      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.status);
      if(response.status == "incomplete"){
        //do something here
      }

    }
  }
 });
}
```

The console prints `{"status": "incomplete"}` for the first console log and `undefined` for the console.log function accessing the status element.

I tried using `JSON.parse(response)` but I get the error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a` in the jquery.js file which I believe is indicating that the object is already a JSON object.  However, if I check the type of the object, it displays string.  How can I access the elements of the response JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the Json back into a JS object when it's received. Otherwise, it's just text.

jQuery will do that for you if you specify `dataType: "json"` in the Ajax call.

Comment: parsing the object with Parse.json(response) throws an error similar to parsing an object that is already a Json object.  Also, I tried dataType: json and my ajax request never reaches the success function.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  It turns out that my Django setup was returning some additional string items so when I tried to set dataType: "json" (as @Daniel Roseman suggested) or in the jQuery function or use JSON.parse(response) I received an error.  I was able to remove the extra string and it worked properly.